# Cocos2d Main Menu using Picker views

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating sort of a game/study app, and part of it requires you to pick which category  you want to study, and then a subcategory after that.

so like Math > Algebra.

I really wanted this to be two Picker Views right next to each other, so basically the first picker has the big categories like Math, Science and all of those. And the next picker would have the sub-categories of each one of the big categories and would change depending on which category is currently selected on the main one.

I however, have no idea how to do this in Cocos2d, as I've said in my other questions I'm pretty new to iOS.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread on Cocos 2d forum about a CGPicker class that hm50 wrote to perform the kind of function you need. Should get you what you want.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10160

All you need to do then is recognise a select and change the contents of your second picker depending on what was selected.